# How to add gtk2 theme to KDE?

Tags: kde, gtk, theme

I'm trying to find a good GTK theme that I like for certain applications. Trouble is, I don't use Gnome-- I have OpenSUSE 12.2 x64 with KDE 4.9 only. So if I've downloaded a theme tarball, what can I do to make KDE aware of it? Is it a matter of putting it in a certain location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System-wide themes are stored in `/usr/local/share/themes`; user themes are stored in `~/.themes`. You will need to create or edit the files `~/.gtkrc-2.0` and `~/.gtkrc-2.0-kde4`. 
There is also a GUI interface in KDE Control Center, GTK Styles and Fonts. Example:

```
$ cat .gtkrc-2.0-kde4
# This file was written by KDE
# You can edit it in the KDE control center, under "GTK Styles and Fonts"

# Include gtkrc for the desired themes
include "/usr/local/share/themes/mytheme/gtk-2.0/gtkrc"
gtk-theme-name="mytheme"
gtk-font-name="myfont"
```

Comment: What I actually meant was how to "install" the theme. I saw from your answer /usr/local/share/themes, so I unzipped my tarball and put the theme folder in there. After that it showed up in the KDE control center.

Comment: Great, editing answer to reflect that.